# Creating an array of ArrayList which store object of Generic type

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I have to create an array of ArrayList which is storing an object of the generic type.

```
ArrayList<Entry>[] bucket;
```

when I initialize this to

```
bucket=(ArrayList<Entry>[])new Object[m];
```

I get **java.lang.ClassCastException** at runtime.

`Entry` class uses generics. Below is the code:

```
class Entry<K,V>{
    K key;
    V value;

    public Entry(K key,V value){
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
    }
```

After going through several posts on why Array of Objects cannot be cast to an ArrayList of a generic type, I have understood my problem. But I am not able to get my head around this to solve my particular case.

Some of the solutions involved:

Changing it **FROM** "an array of ArrayList" **TO** "an ArrayList of ArrayList",
but I can not do that in my case.

Full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class MyHashMap<K,V>  {

    int m;
    int loadFactor;
    int n;

    ArrayList<Entry>[] bucket;

    public MyHashMap(){
        this(10,2);
    }
    public MyHashMap(int m){
        this(m,2);
    }
    public MyHashMap(int m,int loadFactor){
        this.m=m;
        this.loadFactor=loadFactor;
        n=0;

        bucket=(ArrayList<Entry>[])new Object[m];

    }

    class Entry{
        K key;
        V value;

        public Entry(K key,V value){
            this.key=key;
            this.value=value;
        }

        public int hashCode(){
            return 0;
        }
    }


    public void put(K key, V value){    
        Entry entry=new Entry(key,value);
        int hash=entry.hashCode();
        int index=hash%m;
        bucket[index].add(entry);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyHashMap hashMap=new MyHashMap();

        hashMap.put("faisal",2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you create  a class called `Entry` which looks awfully similar to Java's `Map.Entry`?

Comment: why do you think you can cast a `Object` array into an array of `ArrayList<Entry>` ?

Comment: Please show the code in context where you plan to use this `ArrayList`.

Comment: Polymorphic type declaration doesn't work with collections.The type should be exact type.it cant be parent or subtype.but this is diff from with arrays.`Entry[] bucket=new Object[m];`

Comment: @Tim I am actually implementing HashMap here,and  I am using chaining.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added the rest of the code in problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create arrays of generic type. Use this instead:

```
ArrayList<Entry>[] bucket = new ArrayList[m];
```

It shows unchecked warning though, which you can suppress using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Entry>[] bucket = new ArrayList[m];
```

Comment: The compiler does not complain nor there is any problem at runtime. I am now wondering if it is okay to do that.! I mean is this the only option left.

Comment: It's fine to do it if you know you are going to store only the ArrayList<Entry> objects in it. Better not to expose it outside your API class.

Answer (score 0):

Object can be cast to ArrayList only if the actual object it holds is an arrayList. i.e let's look at the below code,

```
Object obj = new ArrayList<String>();   // object variable holding array list type.
ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) obj;
```

Comment: Question is about array of array list